# Play video according to response from AJAX GET

Tags: javascript, html

I have a server application which returns a HTML 5 video URL on AJAX GET request.
How do I render this URL on the client side and play it in video Tag

Comment: You need to show us some code and sample of response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily add a source element inside video tag on successful ajax request. (I have omitted ajax request in this example, but you can easily use the returned URL from AJAX request in the following code)

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var source = document.createElement('source');

source.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4'); //use your AJAX response URL here.

video.appendChild(source);
video.play();
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/f990cmem/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll use that and insert the response URL from my server.